# Do a SetState inmediatly after log in

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a setState everytime the user pass the log in phase. "litems" is a list of items, that I use in "MyHomePage" for a listView. But when the user pass to "MyHomePage" the list "litems" have all the elements but the listView does not update therefore the listView does not show anything until a SetState happends in "MyHomePage"

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      uid = firebaseUser.uid;
      Database db = new Database(uid);
      db.getListPersonalReminder(litems); //Add all the necessary elements in litems
      return MyHomePage(litems);
    }
    return SignInPage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert this
 
>  StatelessWidget widget to StatefulWidget and Then 

void initState() {
super.initState();
---- do your task here 
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.